# Find minimum values among the 5 integers?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to find the minimum of 5 integer values. i have used if else statement to compare. So its not looking good. i.e. code is very lengthy. I dont know how to reduce the code complexity.
can anyone help me out?

Regards, 
Karthi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339189.aspx) method of LINQ.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Min` method from LINQ:

```
var list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int min = list.Min();
```

Here is the list of LINQ `Min` you can refer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx

Comment: Good if they're already in an array or you don't mind creating such an array. +1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Math.Min` method for an efficient way to get the minimum:

```
int min = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(n1, n2) ,n3), n4), n5);
```

---

Some other options that may be more readable (and scaleable), but not quite as efficient:

```
int min = new int[]{ n1, n2, n3, n4, n5}.Min();

int min = new SortedSet<int>() { n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 }[0];
```

Comment: Good if they're not in an array, though, it won't scale. But, since the Q said 5 only, then +1. Though, I'd probably create my own `Min5(a,b,c,d,e)` function to make it look nicer.

Comment: It would be more readable to put the values into an array first, IMHO.

Comment: @driis: Yes, that is an option, but this is more efficient. I wanted to show an option where you don't have to create an array.